# Filtering inputs by value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML construction like this

```
<div class="qn-block">
    <a href="#" class="remove"></a>
    <input type="text" class="quantity-number" name="quantity-number" value="2" />
    <a href="#" class="add"></a>
    <a href="#" class="refresh-q">Refresh</a>
</div>
```

For inputs with value > 1 i have to disable ".refresh-q". For inputs with value = 1 disable ".refresh-q" and ".remove".
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to *disable* an anchor you could define a `click` handler which returns false:

```
function disableAnchor() {
    return false;
}
```

But you could also hide it or whatever.

and then:

```
$('.quantity-number').each(function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (isNaN(value)) {
        return;    
    }

    if (value > 1) {
        $(this).siblings('.refresh-q').addClass('disabled').click(disableAnchor);
    } else if (value === 1) {
        $(this).siblings('.refresh-q, .remove').addClass('disabled').click(disableAnchor);

    }
});
```

Comment: I think it's better to use .show(), hide() instead of click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You cannot disable a link, so I have simply hidden them. There are alternatives to simply hiding the element, such as removing the A element completely, or returning false when clicked, if you'd prefer to use those instead.

```
$(".quantity-number").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val()
    if (val = 1) {
        $(this).siblings(".refresh-q, .remove").hide();
    }
    else if (val > 1) {
        $(this).siblings(".refresh-q").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: in my case .change() doesn't work. i was needed to use .each() function like in the first reply. besides it's (val == 1) instead of (val = 1). anyway, thnx. )